# How to display image over main website using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an old PHP site running on apache that I want to slowly shut down but first I need to notify the visitors. I don't want to get involved in editing the site code itself so I'm hoping I can use htaccess and php_value auto_append_file /home/username/public_html/file.php to show a discrete notice to all visitors of the site that doesn't affect the operations of the old site itself but I'm not sure how best to implement the php side.

I have an image and was wondering if there was a way to show just the image wihtout extra html as an overlay in the bottom corner using a PHP file to load the image and the htaccess to invoke the necessary php file

Comment: My suggestion would be to add some JS for the notice even though you don't want to edit the code. Using auto_append_file may not work for you depending on the code (i.e. it's not reliable given current information).

Comment: I was thinking js might be needed but don't really know where to start with it